# Maven Embedded Glassfish Plugin - Datasource and JDBC driver

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-plugin, glassfish-3, glassfish-embedded

I'm trying to follow [this](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2011/02/glassfish-embedded-jpa-ejb-datasource.html) approach to create a datasource for embedded glassfish. The only significant difference between the tutorial and my code is that I'm running the server using the official maven plugin and the `embedded-glassfish:run` goal.

There is a dependency for the JDBC driver in the pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.155</version>
</dependency>
```

And my `glassfish-resources.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/myDatasource" object-type="user" pool-name="connectionPool">
    <description/>
  </jdbc-resource>
  <jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"  name="connectionPool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:h2:~/Documents/Projetos/DBs/h2/glassfish/glassfish;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MVCC=TRUE"/>
    <property name="User" value="sa"/>
    <property name="Password" value=""/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

It runs fine using a local glassfish server. But no lucky with the embedded instance:

> 03/06/2011 19:26:31
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle
>   deploy GRAVE: Invalid resource :
>   jdbc/myDatasource_*pm
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid
>   resource : jdbc/myDatasource*_pm  at
>   com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:539)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:468)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
>     at

I'm clueless... Can anyone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. It had nothing to do with `glassfish-resources.xml` after all. The jdbc resource was properly created and bound to `java:app/jdbc/myDatasource`.

My persistence unit (generated by Netbeans) was looking for `jdbc/myDatasource` and not finding anything.
I ended up changing my persistence unit to point to the application namespace:

```
<jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/myDatasource</jta-data-source>
```

Another option would be using the `embedded-glassfish:admin` goal to deploy a global resource with non-standard name (so that I could use `jdbc/myDatasource`). But going standard seemed like the best approach.

[This](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/gf-31-non-standard-jndi-names) topic was very helpful.